# Encoding csv-file with php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I do import the csv-file in mysql table. But because of wrong encoding some fields empty. The problem is solved if I do the convert to UTF-8 in Notepad++. Can I do this with php when i fopen this file? I've tried:

```
$file = fopen($csvfile,"r");

$file = mb_convert_encoding($file, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($file));
```

It gave me an Warning: mb_internal_encoding() expects at most 1 parameter

Comment: Read data from the file and use mb_convert_encoding() on that data, not on the file handle

Comment: Or even set a [stream context](http://php.net/manual/en/stream.contexts.php) for the file to convert the encoding

Comment: @MarkBaker Can you write the example of how to do it, pls?

Answer (score 0):

You are get this error because the first parameter of **fgetcsv** function must be "Path of CSV file", so try writing this line `echo $file;` it will be display **Resource id** ***#NUMBER***

To solve the issue, delete that line.